# Python windows multiprocessing with global imports

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

I've been tasked with porting some Python code that works perfectly on Linux, to Windows.  Unfortunately the code fails with the error:

> An attempt has been made to start a new process before current
>   process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

From what I've been reading this is all due to Windows not using fork, and instead using spawn to create new threads.

This is where I'd post code, but there's a problem also, there is so much of it.  One file imports another, which imports another, which starts threads, which has another class that also spawns a new thread.

So from what I've been reading, it's just a matter of using the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard to prevent an infinite loop of threads from spawning, but I don't know where to put it.

The python file that I run already has this in place, but threads are spawned from other methods in other classes, so do I also need to put it into those classes?

It also seems that whomever wrote this has used a global file, which gets imported into each of the separate python files, and than in turn also imports other Python files.  Sorry for not giving any code, but I really don't even know where to start with this one.

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Just to clear up any potential confusion, it appears this code is using process, not threads.  So there is code like

```
import multiprocessing as mp
....
manager = mp.Manager()
...
process = mp.Process(blah)
process.start()
process.join()
....
process.terminate()
```

---

To add some more information, after making some minor changes, I've got the program to run.  It's using Flask to to provide a REST API, that runs functions when it receives various HTTP requests.

It's currently throwing this exception when calling

```
manager = mp.Manager()
```

This line is part of the global.py file that is used in each of the other python files.

---

OK, after some modifications, I've now got past that problem, and onto another one!  The processes are now starting, but the variables aren't available when imported from another class, for example

```
global.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    thingy = manager.dict()
```

---

```
handler.py
from global import *
if thingy['status'] == 'working':
**NameError: name 'thingy' is not defined**
```

Comment: First, threads or process? That's 2 different thing.

Comment: Sorry, it's using process.  with process.start() and process.join()

Comment: Each module has to be side effects free. Only the main function has to be put inside this `if __name__`.

Comment: The only use of the if __name__ is currently in the main function, so that's OK.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'side effects free'

Comment: All the part with the manager, the process.start(), process.stop() should be placed IN the if statement `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: So I do need to use the if statement in places other than the main function?

Comment: That's the problem with global variables. You cannot create `manager` in `global.py` but have to move this code into a function, that is called by the main function.